# Getting page information from page source by name in C++

Tags: c++, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to make a C++ program that searches a URL and picks out text by its name. I know this is achievable in python with requests and beautiful-soup, however I am trying to do this in C++. I have had a look at `cURL` and so far this is what I have in terms of its functionality

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>


static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  std::string readBuffer;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.barcodelookup.com/763649064870");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);


    std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the page from the program does not include the text when viewed in a browser as displayed next to the name. For example, I am interested in picking out (from the source of `https://www.barcodelookup.com/763649064870` this line here (5): `<meta name="description" content="Barcode Lookup provides info on UPC 763649064870 - Seagate 1Tb Expansion Portable Drive USB.">` in python I would just find `<meta name="description" ....` however in my C++ program I don't get that. The output is actually:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>

<meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>
```

and that is just for the first portion of the output, but that in theory should have covered line 5 (which im interested in). How can I get the proper output as displayed by view page source?

Comment: That looks like you got an error page from CloudFlare. Perhaps you've been hitting the site too frequently?

Comment: Not sure about that... maybe 5 times in the last 5 mins?